# PyQt5: Issues with a Mixin with a metaclass within a derived QWidget class

Tags: python, pyqt5, multiple-inheritance, mixins, metaclass

I'm having issues trying to add a mixin with a metaclass to a class whose base is a QWidget. I'm aware that PyQt5 [supports cooperative multiple inheritance](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/multiinheritance.html) and if my MixIn class has no metaclass then things work fine. However, if it has a metaclass - whether it be the `pyqtWrapperType` metaclass shared by QWidgets or a derived metaclass, then I receive the following error:

`Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

The code for the rest of the script runs, but the QWidget does not show up. Here's the base code (stripped of the methods since I know they're not necessary for the problem)

```
import abc, sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

# Test Metaclass, will have more if metaclasses work
class MyMeta(abc.ABCMeta, QtCore.pyqtWrapperType):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)

# MixIn class - ignore the calls to methods for now
# Have same issue if metaclass set to pyqtWrapperType
class LocatorWidget(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __init__(self, locator=None, name='', parameters={}, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # self.setup_parameters(parameters)
        self.locator = locator
        self.name = name if name else ''
        self.widgetType = self.__class__.__name__.replace('LW', '')
        # self.setup()

# Derived class with a QWidget base
class LWComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox, LocatorWidget):
    def __init__(self, locator, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(locator=locator, **kwargs)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # locator is class in full code, using this as filler for now
    locator=[0,1,2,3]
    cb = LWComboBox(locator=locator)
    cb.addItems([str(x) for x in range(5)])
    # Test to see if attribute is set
    print(cb.locator)

    window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    window.form = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
    window.form.addRow(cb)
    window.setLayout(window.form)

    window.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am *not* having the metaclass conflict error: The base class and derived classes do not have different metaclasses because MyMeta is derived from pyqtWrapperType.

If this process doesn't work I'm wondering if I should stick with my previous idea which was enveloping the widget with the attributes and methods I want to share in a separate class, the widget being one of the attributes, but it'll be nice to subclass QWidgets directly with the necessary abstract methods and attributes.

As an FYI I an running PyCharm 2016.2.3 in Anaconda with PyQt5 version 5.6 (PyQt can't be updated to later versions in Anaconda)

Answer (score 3):

The `pyqtWrapperType` no longer exists. If you want the equivalent type in PyQt5, you can use either:

```
pyqtWrapperType = type(QtCore.QObject)
```

or:

```
from sip import wrappertype as pyqtWrapperType
```

Comment: I haven't had the problem that `pyqtWrapperType` does't exist; a quick check indicates that I don't have the latest version of PyQt5. (I have Anaconda and PyQt5 v 5.60) I'll update and apply your fix and see what happens, but  changing `pyqtWrapperType` to `type(QtCore.QObject)` in the version that I have hasn't seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: After fixing several unrelated bugs in your example, I found it works perfectly fine for me when using the changes I suggested.

Comment: What version of PyQt are you using? According to [http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/What-happend-to-PyQt5-QtCore-pyqtWrapperType-td5207614.html](here), pyqtWrapperType was removed in PyQt 5.7 and is still available in 5.6. Anaconda (which I use) [https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1023](does not support PyQt 5.7). Is this a version issue where I'd have to manually upgrade to 5.7?

When I do `type(QObject)` it returns `pyqtWrapperType` for me in PyQt 5.6.

Comment: FWIW, I'm using PyQt-5.8. Can you please run the example in a console and get a proper traceback? The error message in your question is totally useless and has nothing to do with Python or PyQt.

Comment: I ran it in the vanilla python console (as well as the QtConsole) and it crashes on the same line: `cb = LWComboBox(locator=locator` - it does not link to a particular error. On the regular console, python.exe itself crashes, with the error message `An unhandled win32 exception occured in python.exe [8972]`. On the Jupyter QtConsole, the kernal just crashes with no error message. It works if I make `cb` a QComboBox instead. I have included using `type(QtCore.QObject)` for the metaclass.

Comment: @Bill3000. What version of PyQt5 did you test with, and where did you install it from?