# python metaclass conflict : how to pass additional parameter to meta class apart from the parent class

Tags: python, error-handling, metaclass

This is my code snippet of trying to create a custom exception class which takes a input parameter about the exception

```
class Error(Exception):
    pass
mssg = "None"

class timepasserror(mssg ,Error):

    print(f"the error is {mssg}")
```

and I am planning to use it as mentioned below

```
if 1==1:#some conditon
    raise timepasserror('something')
```

I am getting this error :

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I am not sure if its possible to do so . If yes can anyone guide me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are having an error because you are trying something that does not make sense, trying to inherit from a string instance (`mssg = "None"`) - this will never work.

Otherwise one will see this error (when trying to do things correctly) when trying to inherit from two *classes* which have differing metaclasses, and this question have been asked around plenty of times: the solution would be creating a base metaclass that inherits from both conflicting metaclasses - [Abstract class inheriting from ABC and QMainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68304453/abstract-class-inheriting-from-abc-and-qmainwindow/68307338#68307338)

In your case, please, take a step back and find out how to implement the behavior you want in your custom exception: it won't take multiple inheritance.