# How to correctly inherit from an abc interface and another class preserving restriction to create objects missing implementation?

Tags: python, abc

I'm trying to combine a class implementing an `abc` interface with another class.

Let's start with `abc` simple example:

```
import abc

class Interface(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def pure_virtual_func(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Impl(Interface):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

impl = Impl()
```

This piece of code will fail when impl is created: `Can't instantiate abstract class Impl with abstract methods pure_virtual_func`. This is great, that's what you expect.

Now, when `Impl` needs to derive from another class:

```
import abc
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

class Interface(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def pure_virtual_func(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    
class Impl(QWidget,Interface):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
app = QApplication()
impl = Impl()
```

You get the error: `Error: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`.

According to some posts ([Resolving metaclass conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276037/resolving-metaclass-conflicts) and [Abstract class inheriting from ABC and QMainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68304453/abstract-class-inheriting-from-abc-and-qmainwindow)), it is recommended to do that:

```
import abc
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

class Interface(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def pure_virtual_func(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    
class Meta(type(QWidget), type(Interface)):
    pass
    
class Impl(QWidget, Interface, metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
app = QApplication()
impl = Impl()
```

OK, now the `metaclass` error is gone. But you don't get the error `Can't instantiate abstract class Impl with abstract methods pure_virtual_func` anymore, now the `impl` is simply created, and you'll get the `NotImplementedError` exception if `pure_virtual_func` is called.

The `abc` great feature detecting not implemented pure virtual method is gone, how can one derive from `Interface` and another class (`QWidget` in my exemple) and preserve not implemented pure virtual method detection?

There's many posts explaining how to make the code work with metaclass stuff, but I found none that preserves `abc` capability to detect not implemented pure virtual methods.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Description**

The behavior you are observing is due to the implementation of your new Meta Class bypassing the abstract method checking behavior of `ABCMeta` metaclass for any `abc` abstract class you use which is different from the metaclass `QMetaObject` for `QWidget`.

**Recommendation**
Instead of using inheritance, you can try composition refactor your design to avoid using this method. Python allows multiple parents for a class which leads to the `diamond problem` if not careful. But still if you desire to achieve the behavior requested you due to some ***constraints*** you can try the following.

**Code**

```py
import abc
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import inspect

class Interface(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def pure_virtual_func(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    
class Meta(type(Interface),type(QWidget)):
    pass

    
class Impl(Interface, QWidget, metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self):
        self._check_abstract_methods()
    
    def _check_abstract_methods(self):
        for name, value in inspect.getmembers(type(self), predicate=inspect.isfunction):
            if getattr(value, "__isabstractmethod__", False):
                raise NotImplementedError(f"The abstract method '{name}' is not implemented in '{type(self).__name__}'.")
    
app = QApplication()
new_impl = Impl()
```

Using the inspect module we explicitly check for all memebers of the class if they are an abstract method. If `True` we throw an exception similar to the `abc` module.

Comment: OK, this is nice, Im'm just surprised you have to do this manually...

Comment: I don't think defining the appropriate metaclass is always so straightforward. The algorithm for determining if two metaclasses are "compatible" is overly conservative, because it's either expensive or impossible to determine in general if two given metaclasses are really compatible, or if a definition like `Meta` will work.

Comment: Basically, the definition of `Meta` says "Trust me, it's fine." It's up to you to make sure `Meta` really *is* fine.

Comment: IIUC, `ABC` could be defined with `__init_subclass__` if all it had to do was enforce abstract method overrides. The metaclass is only *needed* to handle virtual subclassing.